# Switch from one "Input dialog box" to another "input dialog box"?

Tags: java, mysql, swing, joptionpane

well hope you all are well..

I'm making a simple `Phone book diary`, so the problem is

When i click `new`, it must open a dialog box `JOptionPane`,

and yes it opens successfully, but after click `ok` i want to show a new dialog box again to ask phone number .. well i know to do coding but looking for a logic how to do that?

here is my source codes:

```
package phonebook;

import javax.swing.*;

public class MainProgram extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public MainProgram() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();
        jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
        jMenu1 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        jMenu2 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        jMenuItem1 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        jMenuItem2 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        jMenuItem3 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Phone book made by Rajendra Arora");

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Segoe UI Semibold", 1, 14)); 
        jLabel1.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jLabel1.setText("Welcome to Phonebook diary!");
        jLabel1.setToolTipText("");

        jLabel2.setText("Made by: Rajendra Arora");
        jLabel2.setToolTipText("");

        jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null},
            },
            new String [] {
                "Name", "Mobile no.", "City", "Country"
            }
        ) {
            Class[] types = new Class [] {
                java.lang.String.class, java.lang.Integer.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class
            };
            boolean[] canEdit = new boolean [] {
                false, false, false, false
            };

            public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                return types [columnIndex];
            }

            public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
                return canEdit [columnIndex];
            }
        });
        jTable1.setToolTipText("");
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);

        jMenu1.setText("File");

        jMenuItem1.setText("New");
        jMenuItem1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jMenu1.add(jMenuItem1);

        jMenuItem2.setText("About");
        jMenuItem2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jMenuItem2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jMenu1.add(jMenuItem2);

        jMenuItem3.setText("Exit");
        jMenuItem3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jMenuItem3ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jMenu1.add(jMenuItem3);

        jMenuBar1.add(jMenu1);

        setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addContainerGap())
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 29, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 286, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
        );

        pack();
    }                      

    private void jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter full name", "Enter full name", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }                                          

    private void jMenuItem3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        System.exit(0);
    }                                          

    private void jMenuItem2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This Phonebook simple diary is made by Rajendra Arora", "About", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }                                          

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainProgram.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainProgram.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainProgram.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainProgram.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new MainProgram().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu1;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu2;
    private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem1;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem2;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem3;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;                 
}
```

Comment: Paste your code and show what have you tried??

Comment: Show us your code. What you have so far and on this code indicates where you want this behavior.

Comment: I edited my question please see that. .

Comment: I'm confused by your question, why not just check if the input was null, if it wasn't use the exact same popup code for the phone number?

Comment: There is no confusion into it.. I'm simply just asking.. how to show another dialog box when first dialog box is appearing after clicking okay!..that's it

Answer (score 0):

This is what you may want

```
int ans=     JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter full name", "Enter full name", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
if(ans==JOptionPane.OK_OPTION)    {
int optionSelected=     JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter phone number", "Enter phone number", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}
```

P.S: This is just to give you the idea.Modify /improve the code as you need. Indeed I haven't checked for the  Syntax or API  while posting this answer.

Comment: Would be better if you this `if(ans.equals(JOptionPane.OK_OPTION)){...}` But really your answer was useful