# My DefaultTableModel is not showing?

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I can't see my `DefaultTableModel` inside my frame please, help .. Where I'm doing wrong?

here is my codes:

```
package phonebook;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;    
import java.awt.Font;    
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class MyProgram {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTable table;
    private DefaultTableModel tableModel;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    MyProgram window = new MyProgram();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public MyProgram() {
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {

        tableModel=new DefaultTableModel();
        tableModel.addColumn("Name");
        tableModel.addColumn("Phone no.");
        tableModel.addColumn("City");
        tableModel.addColumn("Country");

        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        menuBar.setBounds(0, 0, 434, 21);
        frame.getContentPane().add(menuBar);

        JMenu mnFile = new JMenu("File");
        menuBar.add(mnFile);

        JMenuItem mntmNew = new JMenuItem("New ");
        mnFile.add(mntmNew);

        JMenuItem mntmExit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
        mnFile.add(mntmExit);

        JMenu mnAbout = new JMenu("About");
        menuBar.add(mnAbout);

        JMenuItem mntmAbout = new JMenuItem("About");
        mnAbout.add(mntmAbout);

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Welcome to Phonebook diary by Rajendra arora");
        lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        lblNewLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(0, 21, 434, 50);

        frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel);
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        table = new JTable(tableModel);
        table.setBounds(10, 260, 414, -189);
        frame.getContentPane().add(table);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's maybe because you haven't added it to the frame :)

Comment: No, see my code i added it :)

Comment: @RajendraArora, its about time you started "accepting" answer when you are given answers to you questions. You got valid answers here and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24913954/how-to-insert-all-database-values-into-a-column-table-list and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24908535/switch-from-one-input-dialog-box-to-another-input-dialog-box and yet you have not accepted a single answer.

Answer (score 4):

1. `setLayout(null);` `null` layouts will always come back to bite you
2. `frame.add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);` this is going to cause problems when using a `null` layout, as components have a default size of `0x0`. Also, at the time this is called, `table` is `null`
3. `table.setBounds(10, 260, 414, -189)` components can't have a negative size
4. Don't add menu bars to your frame, use `setJMenuBar` instead

As previously recommend, use an appropriate [layout managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html).

If you can't find a single layout manager to meet your needs, don't be afraid to use multiple layouts across multiple containers to build the effect you want